# populate in nodejs and mongoose not worked

Tags: node.js, mongoose, mongoose-populate

i have a Schema for save info , in this info i have a `userId` and i want to return info of that Schema and return info of user form `user` Schema .

**TravelRequestSchema :**

```
 const TravelRequestSchema = new Schema({
    userId: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "User" }
    description: { type: String, require: true }
}, {
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
    toJSON: { virtuals: true }
});
```

**User Schema :**

```
 const UserSchema = new Schema({
    firstName: { type: String },
    lastName: { type: String },
    phoneNumber: { type: String },
    email: { type: String, defult: null }
},{
        toJSON: { virtuals: true }
});
```

now i write this quesy for get info :

```
await TravelRequestModel.find({})
        .populate('User')
        .exec();
```

but it not return the user info for me , it just return the `UserId` .

**now how can i sovle this problem ??**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your query to populate specific fields, not model names

```
await TravelRequestModel.find({})
        .populate('userId')
        .exec();
```

This is because if you had multiple fields that reference the same model, you want to be able to pick and choose which *fields* to populate.